# Use of frame pointer instead of stack pointer when returning from a procedure

Tags: c, gcc, riscv

I have a question about the RISC-V returning from a procedure convention.
By analyzing the assembly code generated from several C programs, I observed that, when returning from a procedure call, the return address is stored in the return address register through a load instruction that uses the stack pointer register as source address.

Here it is an example:

`<main>:
addi sp,sp,-48
sw ra,44(sp)
sw s0,40(sp)
...
...
lw ra,44(sp)
lw s0,40(sp)
addi sp,sp,48
ret`

Is there any option to force the GCC RISC-V compiler to use the "frame pointer" register instead of the "stack pointer" register when calculating the source address of the LOAD instruction that affects the return address?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46570034/edit) to include more information.  Would you please tell us more about your use case?  Why do you want to switch from SP to FP?  There might be a solution to your underlying problem that does not actually require changing the calling convention.

Comment: Just in case someone wonders why he wondered... ;) It was most probably related to his work on this paper on detecting memory corruption bugs in (RISC-V) hardware (cf. section V.B): https://scholar.google.at/scholar?cluster=14474006671409647695&hl=en&as_sdt=0,5&sciodt=0,5